# How to override a requestAnimationFrame loop?

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I'm creating a little ticker on my page to display instructions to the user programmatically. I've got it working nicely:

```
var ticker = document.getElementById('ticker');

function instruct (message) {
  var message = message;
  var letters = message.split('');
  var part = '';

  function animate () {
    if (letters.length !== 0) {
      ticker.textContent = '';
      part += letters.shift();
      ticker.textContent = part;
      return requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } 
  }
  animate();
}
```

It's cute, it looks like it's typing the message out to the user very quickly.

So here are a couple of sample messages:

```
instruct('Great, thanks!');
instruct('What\'s next?');
```

One message at a time works just fine, but when two come at once, the longer one wins out. I need which ever one comes second to cancel, or override, any that are still running.

Not sure how to pull this off cleanly.

Any help would rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cancelAnimationFrame` - just like `clearInterval`

```js
var ticker = document.getElementById('ticker');
var animFrame;
function instruct (message) {
  var message = message;
  var letters = message.split('');
  var part = '';
  
  cancelAnimationFrame(animFrame);

  function animate () {
    if (letters.length !== 0) {
      ticker.textContent = '';
      part += letters.shift();
      ticker.textContent = part;
      return requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } 
  }
  animFrame = animate();
}


setTimeout(function() { instruct('this is a testing message'); },500);
setTimeout(function() { instruct('this is a second testing message'); },600);
```

```html
<div id="ticker"></div>
```